# j2me bluetooth client. Function startInquiry nothing found

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, midp

I develop simple j2me bluetooth client and have problem with bluetooth device search.
Function startInquiry nothing found.

Client : nokia 5220
Server : my pc with bluetooth adapter

All bluetooth devices is on.

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.bluetooth.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

/**
 * @author Администратор
 */
public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements DiscoveryListener
{
    private static Vector vecDevices=new Vector();
    private static String connectionURL=null;
    private LocalDevice localDevice;
    private DiscoveryAgent agent;
    private RemoteDevice remoteDevice;
    private RemoteDevice[] devList;
    private Display display;
    private Form form;

    public void startApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        form = new Form( "Client" );
        try {
            localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        } catch( BluetoothStateException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        form.append("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress()+"\n\n");
        form.append("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName()+"\n\n");

        try {
            agent = localDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent();

            form.append("Starting device inquiry... \n\n");

            boolean si = agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC,  this);
            if ( si ) {
                form.append("true");
            } else {
                form.append("false");
            }
        } catch( BluetoothStateException e ) {
        }

        int deviceCount = vecDevices.size();
        if(deviceCount <= 0){
            form.append("No Devices Found .");
        }
        else{
            //print bluetooth device addresses and names in the format [ No. address (name) ]
            form.append("Bluetooth Devices: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++) {
                remoteDevice=(RemoteDevice)vecDevices.elementAt(i);
                form.append( remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress() );
            }
        }

            display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

        public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
              //add the device to the vector
              if(!vecDevices.contains(btDevice)){
                  vecDevices.addElement(btDevice);
              }
        }
        public void inquiryCompleted(int discType)
        {
        }


          //implement this method since services are not being discovered
          public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
              if(servRecord!=null && servRecord.length>0){
                  connectionURL=servRecord[0].getConnectionURL(0,false);
              }
          }
          //implement this method since services are not being discovered
          public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the exact problem is, but you definitely don't want to be doing this in your midlet's `startApp()` method.  This is a system lifecycle method, and should return quickly, but scanning for bluetooth devices will block it for a long time.  Your `startApp()` method is tying up the device's resources which it could need for doing the actual scanning!

Refactor, so your device scanning is done in a new thread, then see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood how the Bluetooth API works. The `startInquiry` method only *starts* the device discovery process and returns immediately afterwards, leaving the discovery running in the background. When devices are discovered, you get a callback of the `deviceDiscovered` method for each of them, and when the discovery process has completed, you get a callback of the `inquiryCompleted` method. So you need to move the accessing of the `vecDevices` member and the form manipulation from `startApp` to `inquiryCompleted` to be able to actually show the discovered information.

Answer (score 0):

You say all devices are **on** - but also check if all devices are **discoverable**.

I've made this mistake before myself!

Lookup the method LocalDevice.setDiscoverable() if you want to toggle between modes programatically.